# Plugin custom post template; without overriding all posts

Tags: plugin-development, posts, templates

I've created a plugin and I am trying to include an post template that the user can optionally use.

I've tried the following,

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'insert_my_template' );

function insert_my_template( $template )
{
if ( 'events' === get_post_type() )
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-events.php';

return $template;
}
```

However this only seems to completely override the template, it does not allow the user to select a different template for use. How can I achieve a similar result to when adding the template into the theme folder while keeping it all in the plugin? (Where the user can choose which template to be displayed)
Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better way to do it, but you can use the [`theme_<post type>_templates` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_post_type_templates/) to add your custom template to the "Template" dropdown, and then use the `template_include` filter to ensure *the correct file is loaded*.

So something like this should work:

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_events_template_include' );
function my_events_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( 'events' === get_post_type() ) {
        $file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-events.php';
        return ( $file === get_page_template_slug() ) ? $file : $template;
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'theme_events_templates', 'my_plugin_theme_events_templates' );
function my_plugin_theme_events_templates( $post_templates ) {
    $file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/single-events.php';
    $post_templates[ $file ] = __( 'Single Events', 'your-text-domain' );
    return $post_templates;
}
```

Note: The array key of `$post_templates` should be a file name/path relative to the active theme directory, but since we're using a full filesystem path, then we had to use the `template_include` filter to load **the correct file from the plugin directory**.

Comment: Oooohhhhh, WOW! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help!
Am I understanding this correctly?

So, $post_templates is an array of templates, and in the plugin we're adding to the array with our template.
Then in template_include, we are checking if the selected template is our template and supplying the correct path. The reason we need to do this is bc it $post_templates is supposed to be relative to the theme folder, but it's in our plugin.

Comment: Glad I could help, and yes, you've understood that correctly 